# What is this style of illustration used in Arabian Nights, illustrated by Vera Bock?

Tags: illustration, drawing, style-identification

I have had this copy of Arabian Nights, collected by Andrew Lang, published around 1960 in Great Britain, in which the illustrations were done by Vera Bock. I have always been mesmerized by them. I would like to know what this style/technique is called, if it has a name. A reverse image search just returns other illustrations from the same book and I haven't been able to find a name/term/style that I can use as a search term. I want to be able to search for other similar works of art, including other artists.

[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuPGA.jpg)

[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEEZR.jpg)

[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aADkK.jpg)

[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT07o.jpg)

Comment: It's also possible that V.B. has created something original and no imitator has been effective enough to degrade that originality to "one of the users of certain style" If you make an image search "Vera Bock" you find many images with characters resembling your examples. In addition you'll see that V.B. made also different things. If you want to take a style name into use, let it be for example "Vera Bock's fairy tale illustration style."

Comment: I concur with @Billy Kerr, that the images are representative of the times when they were created. (i.e., theatre, movies, plays, costume design, sets, etc.). If you search on bing for Vera Bock art, and you click on one of the images, you'll be presented with similar artwork by other artists to the right of the UI.

Comment: Check out Boris Artzybasheff (1899-1965), an Ukrainian artist and a friend of Vera Bock, who came to this country in 1919. His illustrations are similar to Bock's, but contain an irony missing in Bock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than very generic terms such as [line art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_art), not every style of illustration has a specific name.

I'd suggest this style is probably somewhat unique to the artist. There are obvious Art-Deco influences, indicative of the era of Vera Bock's formative years (1920-30s). However, her illustrations of Lang's "Arabian Nights" date to 1946.

I suppose you could describe these as Art Deco influenced line art illustrations.